# Swift Nested If statements do not compile

Tags: swift, if-statement

I need to have a nested "If statements" and cant quite get it to work - keep getting an error - expected expression right at the last curley brace.

The below code is what i've tried:

```
if weightLabel.text == "Weight (lbs)" {
      if pickerView == heightPicker {
            let titleRow = height[row]
             return titleRow
      } else if pickerView == weightPicker {
                let titleRow = weight[row]
                return titleRow
              }
         return ""
        else if weightLabel.text == "Weight (kgs)" {
            if pickerView == heightPicker {
                let titleRow = heightCM[row]
                return titleRow
            }
            else if pickerView == weightPicker {
                let titleRow = weightKG[row]
                return titleRow
            }
            return ""
         }
 }
```

Can someone take a look at my current code and help?

Comment: For a starter, there should be a `}` before `else if`

Comment: Where exactly do you get that error?

Comment: already fixed with the chosen answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
func getWeight() -> String {
    if weightLabel.text == "Weight (lbs)" {
        if pickerView == heightPicker {
            let titleRow = height[row]
            return titleRow
        }
        else if pickerView == weightPicker {
            let titleRow = weight[row]
            return titleRow
        }
        return ""
    }
    else if weightLabel.text == "Weight (kgs)" {
        if pickerView == heightPicker {
            let titleRow = heightCM[row]
            return titleRow
        }
        else if pickerView == weightPicker {
            let titleRow = weightKG[row]
            return titleRow
        }
        return ""
    }
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have return statements everywhere you can skip all `else`

```
if weightLabel.text == "Weight (lbs)" {
    if pickerView == heightPicker {
        return height[row]
    }
    if pickerView == weightPicker {
        return weight[row]
    }
}

if weightLabel.text == "Weight (kgs)" {
    if pickerView == heightPicker {
        return heightCM[row]
    }

    if pickerView == weightPicker {
         return weightKG[row]
    }
}
return ""
```

Another way to do it is to use a local variable that is set in the if/else clauses and then returned

```
var titleRow = ""
if weightLabel.text == "Weight (lbs)" {
    if pickerView == heightPicker {
        titleRow = height[row]
    } else if pickerView == weightPicker {
        titleRow = weight[row]
    }
} else if weightLabel.text == "Weight (kgs)" {
    if pickerView == heightPicker {
        titleRow = heightCM[row]
    } else if pickerView == weightPicker {
        titleRow = weightKG[row]
    }
}

return titleRow
```